# Monotouch data sync - why does my code sometimes cause sqlite errors?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I have the following calls (actually a few more than this - it's the overall method that's in question here):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Database.Instance.RefreshEventData);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Database.Instance.RefreshLocationData);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Database.Instance.RefreshActData);
```

1st point is - is it OK to call methods that call WCF services like this? I tried daisy chaining them and it was a mess.

An example of one of the refresh methods being called above is (they all follow the same pattern, just call different services and populate different tables):

```
public void RefreshEventData (object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("in RefreshEventData");
            var eservices = new AppServicesClient (new BasicHttpBinding (), new EndpointAddress (this.ServciceUrl));

            //default the delta to an old date so that if this is first run we get everything
            var eventsLastUpdated = DateTime.Now.AddDays (-100);

            try {
                eventsLastUpdated = (from s in GuideStar.Data.Database.Main.Table<GuideStar.Data.Event> ()
                    orderby s.DateUpdated descending
                    select s).ToList ().FirstOrDefault ().DateUpdated;

            } catch (Exception ex1) {
                Console.WriteLine (ex1.Message);
            }

            try {
                eservices.GetAuthorisedEventsWithExtendedDataAsync (this.User.Id, this.User.Password, eventsLastUpdated);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine ("error updating events: " + ex.Message);
            }

            eservices.GetAuthorisedEventsWithExtendedDataCompleted += delegate(object sender, GetAuthorisedEventsWithExtendedDataCompletedEventArgs e) {

                try {

                    List<Event> newEvents = e.Result.ToList ();

                    GuideStar.Data.Database.Main.EventsAdded = e.Result.Count ();

                    lock (GuideStar.Data.Database.Main) {
                        GuideStar.Data.Database.Main.Execute ("BEGIN");

                        foreach (var s in newEvents) {

                            GuideStar.Data.Database.Main.InsertOrUpdateEvent (new GuideStar.Data.Event { 
                                Name = s.Name, 
                                DateAdded = s.DateAdded, 
                                DateUpdated = s.DateUpdated, 
                                Deleted = s.Deleted, 
                                StartDate = s.StartDate,
                                Id = s.Id, 
                                Lat = s.Lat, 
                                Long = s.Long   
                            });

                        }

                        GuideStar.Data.Database.Main.Execute ("COMMIT");
                        LocationsCount = 0;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine("error InsertOrUpdateEvent " + ex.Message);
                } finally {
                    OnDatabaseUpdateStepCompleted (EventArgs.Empty);
                }

            };
        }
```

OnDatabaseUpdateStepCompleted - just iterates an updateComplete counter when it's called and when it knows that all of the services have come back ok it removes the waiting spinner and the app carries on.

This works OK 1st time 'round - but then sometimes it doesn't with one of these: http://monobin.com/__m6c83107d

I think the 1st question is - is all this OK? I'm not used to using threading and locks so I am wandering into new ground for me. Is using QueueUserWorkItem like this ok? Should I even be using lock before doing the bulk insert/update? An example of which:

```
public void InsertOrUpdateEvent(Event festival){

            try {
                if (!festival.Deleted) {
                    Main.Insert(festival, "OR REPLACE");
                }else{
                    Main.Delete<Event>(festival);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("InsertOrUpdateEvent failed: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Then the next question is - what am I doing wrong that is causing these sqlite issues?

w://

Comment: To throw some ideas into the mix here - i'm thinking about just generating the sqlite db on the server, downloading it and then using 'restore' to import the new data. Quite clumsy and probably quite heavy but at least it'll work everytime! For the record, these updates are always one way. server -> iphone

Comment: That could work. We did the same with a SQL Server -> SQL CE (the OLD one) replication scenario. Ended up with master -> 400 slave's (on SQL Server), then 1:1 master->slave from sql server (one of the 400DB's) to sql ce (device).

Worked ok, but really, wasn't that good a solution. On the up side, you can compress and generally pack your DB down, and it'd also make your phone logic so much less complicated....

Comment: cvista,
Have you accomplished your Syncing goal? Would you be willing to share some/all of your knowledge? I'm working on a similar problem and would hate to re-create the wheel, if I don't have to.

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: hey. i can't share the code i'm afraid as it's a core part of one of our products. my advice would be to manage threads properly, manage object lifestyles properly and be careful. when it goes off - it goes off and it's a pain to debug. sorry i can't be much more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, no specific answers, but some thoughts:

Is SqlLite even threadsafe? I'm not sure - it may be that it's not (to the wrapper isn't). Can you lock on a more global object, so no two threads are inserting at the same time?

It's possible that the MT GC is getting a little overenthusiastic, and releasing your string before it's been used. Maybe keep a local reference to it around during the insert? I've had this happen with view controllers, where I had them in an array (tabcontrollers, specificially), but if I didn't keep an member variable around with the reference, they got GC'ed.

Could you get the data in a threaded manner, then queue everything up and insert them in a single thread? Atleast as a test anyway.

Comment: So you think maybe if I just have a lock object on the singleton class i use for various things it should be ok? Why oh why isnt sqlite threadsafe? GuideStar.Data.Database.Main is another singleton class, i followed the pattern miguel used in tweetsharp. locking that would lock anything from running anything against the db at the same time no?

Comment: "Could you get the data in a threaded manner" i.e. cache to local collections then one collection after the other insert their contents? I did do this before, kinda, but it had a similar effect.

Comment: sqllite may be threadsafe. the wrapper may not be. I dont know, to be honest. But yeah - some kind of locking in your database object may help. Or see what happens if you just make 1 method, in one thread, and call the three methods in sequence?

Comment: Looks like eservices.GetAuthorisedEventsWithExtendedDataCompleted is being gc'd before the service returns!! how can I keep a reference to _that_?! eeek

Comment: Actually managed to get this rock solid by cutting down the number of calls, refactoring some uneeded payloads and making sure everythign was kept in scope when needed. I will be blogging about this as it cost us a lot of trouble and i'm sure there are a lot of MT devs who will want to do slightly more complex data sync...

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite is not thread safe.

If you want to access Sqlite from more than one thread, you must take a lock before you access any SQLite related structures.

Like this:

```
lock (db){
      // Do your query or insert here
}
```

Comment: should this be done on reads as well as writes? I have actually managed to get it solid now but for reference - and to negate any future issues - i am currently only doing this on writes

Comment: It should be done *anytime* you access Sqlite.   Reads, Writes, or probing for *anything*.